# Different authentication techniques

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, auth0

Can someone tells me the difference in *OAuth2, Auth0, JWT* in a **concise** way and when to use either one and which one is much better?

Comment: As a side note, JWT and OAuth are ways to implement authentication/authorisation, while Auth0 is a service provider; [here's an example of using Auth0's service and JWT to provide auth for a Flask app in Python](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/python/01-authorization).

Answer (score 0):

***[OAuth2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)*** is the name of the protocol you can use to get tokens that can be used to perform an action on behalf of the user.  Now these tokens can be used to access some 3rd party API or your own Service.

For example, if you wanted to access [someones emails on Outlook](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/quick-start) for an app you're building, [OAuth2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)  allows you to get an Access token (issued by Microsoft) on the end user's behalf (they have to sign in to the identity provider) that can be used in a *bearer request* (just an HTTP request w/ the Access token).

Highly recommend skimming the RFC to read about the different scenarios OAuth2.0 can be used, the example here is just one case.

***[JWT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519)*** (JSON Web token) is the standard format of a token used by many identity providers.  Those Access tokens above may come in this format.  Here's a [small site](http://calebb.net/) you can use to decode JWT tokens (try hitting the example token).

***Auth0*** is a private company that works in the Identity space.